# C# Aspose.Cells.dll installation error

Tags: c#, .net, aspose-cells

I have recently wrote a program in C#, and utilizing Aspose.Cells.dll in order to export my reports in Excel format. I installed my program on my computer and some of my friends' it works fine, but today when I faced a clean computer(which has no .net framework or any programming frameworks), the installer installed the prerequisites (.Net Framework 3.5), and the program is launching, but when it comes to use the Aspose.Cells.dll it throws this exception:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Aspose.Cells, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=716fcc553a201e56' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
File name: 'Aspose.Cells, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=716fcc553a201e56' ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer
   at PersonalTimeComputer.Code.MultiExporter.SelectedtoTpcXLS(List`1 selected, String xls_save_path, Dictionary`2 personList)
   at PersonalTimeComputer.UI.PersonalTimeComputerForm.exportToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)




************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
PersonalTimeComputer
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Mehrazar/Desktop/Time%20Attendance/PersonalTimeComputer.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
SourceGrid
    Assembly Version: 4.30.3817.19618
    Win32 Version: 4.30.3817.19618
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Mehrazar/Desktop/Time%20Attendance/SourceGrid.DLL
----------------------------------------
FarsiLibrary.Win
    Assembly Version: 1.9.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.9.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Mehrazar/Desktop/Time%20Attendance/FarsiLibrary.Win.DLL
----------------------------------------
FarsiLibrary.Resources
    Assembly Version: 1.9.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.9.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Mehrazar/Desktop/Time%20Attendance/FarsiLibrary.Resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
FarsiLibrary.Utils
    Assembly Version: 1.9.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.9.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Mehrazar/Desktop/Time%20Attendance/FarsiLibrary.Utils.DLL
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.GridView
    Assembly Version: 2010.1.10.504
    Win32 Version: 2010.1.10.0504
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Mehrazar/Desktop/Time%20Attendance/Telerik.WinControls.GridView.DLL
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.UI
    Assembly Version: 2010.1.10.504
    Win32 Version: 2010.1.10.0504
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Mehrazar/Desktop/Time%20Attendance/Telerik.WinControls.UI.DLL
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls
    Assembly Version: 2010.1.10.504
    Win32 Version: 2010.1.10.0504
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Mehrazar/Desktop/Time%20Attendance/Telerik.WinControls.DLL
----------------------------------------
TelerikCommon
    Assembly Version: 2010.1.10.504
    Win32 Version: 2010.1.10.0504
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Mehrazar/Desktop/Time%20Attendance/TelerikCommon.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.21022.8 built by: RTM
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.21022.8 built by: RTM
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

As you can see it has loaded all the other dlls but not this dll. Does this dll needs another prerequisite than .Net Framework 3.5?

Or is there any idea or some backward compatibility for this dll?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a signing issue. Aspose.Cells is a strong-named assembly, the error you're getting here means the CLR in the test machine is unable to find corresponding public key to verify the .dll's signature. It looks like you'll need to [resign the assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41%28VS.71%29.aspx).

[Previous post with a similar problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989037/mstest-code-coverage)

Comment: I think my problem is also due to signing but how can I sign again my dll I didn't get from the posts how can I do it is it possible through C#? or anything else?

Comment: And when I go to the properties of my dll it says it has a digital signature and it's not valid is it causing the problem

Comment: It is possible to sign a library through Visual Studio if that's what you're asking. If you are building the .dll from the source code, you can press Alt+Enter on the project (or right click, then Properties) and go to the 'Signing' tab. Verify that the check box "Sign the assembly" is checked and a strong name key file is selected. (Also ensure that "Delay sign only" is unchecked).

If you don't have the source code, you will have to resign the .dll. There are some links in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220519/how-to-sign-a-net-assembly-dll-file-with-a-strong-name) to help.